# Is it ok to add access_token authorities to the OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken?

Tags: authorization, spring-security-oauth2, oauth2client

I have a simple spring boot application with two services - `ui` and `resource`.
I trying to configure oauth2+oidc authentication using uaa server.

When I login in the `ui` service, spring security creates authentication result (in OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider) using `id_token` and it doesn't contain any scopes except `openid`. When the authentication result is created it contains only one authority - `ROLE_USER` so a can't use authorization on the client side.

Is is ok to override `OidcUserService` and add to the user's authorities scopes from the access_token to check access on the client side?

```
    @Override
    public OidcUser loadUser(OidcUserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        OidcUser user = super.loadUser(userRequest);
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildAuthorities(
                user,
                userRequest.getAccessToken().getScopes()
        );
        return new DefaultOidcUser(
                authorities,
                userRequest.getIdToken(),
                user.getUserInfo()
        );
    }
```

Security configuration:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/protected/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_protected")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .oauth2Login()
                .userInfoEndpoint().oidcUserService(oidcUserService())
                .and()
            ...
```

It works but I'm not sure it's a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the approach as outlined in the [Spring Security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities-oauth2userservice), so the approach is fine. 
The only thing is that when I have implemented it, I didn't add all the scopes to the authorities set - I pulled out the specific claim that had the role information - a custom `groups` claim that I configured in the identity provider's authorization server.

I include some example code for how to do this with Spring Webflux as most examples show how to do it with Spring MVC as per your code.

note: I'm very inexperienced with using reactor!

```
public class CustomClaimsOidcReactiveOAuth2UserService implements ReactiveOAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> {

    private final OidcReactiveOAuth2UserService service = new OidcReactiveOAuth2UserService();

    public Mono<OidcUser> loadUser(OidcUserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        log.debug("inside CustomClaimsOidcReactiveOAuth2UserService..");

        Mono<OidcUser> mOidcUser = service.loadUser(userRequest);

        return mOidcUser
                .log()
                .cast(DefaultOidcUser.class)
                .map(DefaultOidcUser::getClaims)
                .flatMapIterable(Map::entrySet)
                .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("groups"))
                .flatMapIterable(roleEntry -> (JSONArray) roleEntry.getValue())
                .map(roleString -> {
                    log.debug("roleString={}", roleString);
                    return new OidcUserAuthority((String) roleString, userRequest.getIdToken(), null);
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toSet())
                .map(authorities -> {
                    log.debug("authorities={}", authorities);
                    return new DefaultOidcUser(authorities, userRequest.getIdToken());
                });
    }
}
...
@Bean
ReactiveOAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> userService() {
    return new CustomClaimsOidcReactiveOAuth2UserService();
}
```